# Watson Discovery: Problem with processing data through the API

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-discovery

I'm trying to process **30Mb JSON** file to `Watson Discovery` with the `Node SDK`, but it gives the error that the file is too large. In the documentation, there is explicitly said that we can process up to **50Mb JSON** data with the API.

**Where the issue might come from?** (The JSON has a root array element and each of the objects contain only two Strings)

UPDATE: The JSON file has the following structure

```
{
  "elements":[
    {
       "Q":" ... ",
       "A":" ... "
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

Comment: This is really odd. How are you invoking the service? Does it get to the service invocation in your code? After that is there a proxy or firewall that the request goes through? What is the error, and does it come from the Watson service?

Comment: The service is invoked through the ```Node.JS``` module and the error comes from the **request-wrapper.js** presented in the ```ibm-cloud-sdk-core```. The error code is 413 and comes from ```watson-gateway```.

Answer (score 0):

From the API Documentation - https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/discovery-data#adddocument

> 413 : Too large. Returned if you attempt to add a document or document
> metadata that exceeds the maximum possible.

So either the document or metadata is too large. Your data shouldn't be, so that leaves metadata. Again from the API Documentation -

> metadata string The maximum supported metadata file size is 1 MB.
> Metadata parts larger than 1 MB are rejected.
>
> Example: { "Creator": "Johnny Appleseed", "Subject": "Apples" }

Comment: I don't have a metadata. Just have updated the original post. The data is the one described there.